# Data binding with Kotlin: ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-databinding

I get this error when I type `./gradlew test` in the command line:

```
e: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
        at ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 59 more


> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

It occurs also when I have `kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:$gradlePluginVersion"` (both for 3.2.0 and 3.3.0-alpha13 versions) in build.gradle. I don't have other kapt dependencies. I have data binding enabled, it works and I can run tests via Android Studio (gradle task testDebugUnitTest works). I use embedded JDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Comment: I use embedded JDK

Comment: @WojtekOkoński any luck with this one?

Comment: No, I just don't use this task

Comment: clear explanation is given in this blog https://medium.com/@huih1108/debug-data-binding-with-kotlin-processdatabinding-unable-to-get-public-no-arg-constructor-5f52a710f3e5

Answer (score 17):

I fixed this problem by using Java 8 instead of Java 11. The same problem may appear with Java 9 and 10. I set my `JAVA_HOME` via `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/8` and then ran `./gradlew build`. And voila, no error.

I had the exception `e: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`
 when I ran the build from the command line using gradle. But these didn't appear when I run the build from Android Studio. I suspect this is because Android Studio is somehow using its own version of Java.

Comment: Using Java 8 is a valid workaround - app builds. Is it possible though to run the build using  JDK 11 somehow?

Comment: https://medium.com/@huih1108/debug-data-binding-with-kotlin-processdatabinding-unable-to-get-public-no-arg-constructor-5f52a710f3e5

Answer (score 15):

If you need to use databinding on Java 9+, you'll need to add JAX-B dependencies. Add this to your `build.gradle`'s `dependencies {}` block:

```
// Add missing dependencies for JDK 9+
if (JavaVersion.current().ordinal() >= JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9.ordinal()) {
    // Add both if you're using both Kotlin and Java

    // If you're using Kotlin
    kapt "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
    kapt "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    kapt "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2"

    // If you're using Java
    annotationProcessor "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
    annotationProcessor "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of Java version > 8

Point your JAVA_HOME to Java 8 version, it will work smoothly

Java 8 Download [link](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

Details solution is [here](https://medium.com/@huih1108/debug-data-binding-with-kotlin-processdatabinding-unable-to-get-public-no-arg-constructor-5f52a710f3e5)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor
```

I was getting this error because my '**build.gradle**' , '**kotlin_version**' and '**gradle wrapper**' were not upto date.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10' >> '1.3.20'  
build:gradle:3.5.2  >>  build:gradle:4.2.1  
distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip >> distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```